# Egit and google cloud

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-platform, egit

I am trying to push to a remote repository with EGit.

The remote repository in question is the Google Cloud repository attached to a Google App Engine project. I can run 'git push origin master' to push to it with the command-line git client successfully but, trying to push with EGit asks me to login which the command-line client does not.

If I just click 'OK' without entering anything, I see a 'Push Results' window that shows an error saying the URL of the remote repository is not authorized'.

Anyone knows how to use pushing to remote repo using eclipse and eGit ?

Answer (score 0):

If git is not requesting your credentials every time you may be using git [credential store helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store).
Eclipse stores passwords in its own secure storage. I think you only need to set the credentials one time and specify Eclipse to remember it.

[Eclipse doc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-securestorage-start.htm).

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a [Google Cloud Source Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/)…  There are [two documented ways to configure access to CSR repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes): (1) via a *credential helper*, or (2) via `.gitcookies`.  Unfortunately JGit/EGit do not currently support credential helpers ([feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441198)) nor `.gitcookies` ([feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494643)).

But a Google engineer noted that CSR supports using the OAuth access-token as a password.  I've confirmed this from poking around the Google Cloud SDK-supplied `git-credential-gcloud.sh`. You can obtain your access token with:

`$ gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

Use your account name as the password (your email), and that access token as your password.  Access tokens do expire so be prepared to have to re-enter a password, and it's not worth saving the password into Eclipse's secure storage.

If you have multiple accounts (`gcloud auth list`), you may need to select the right account with `gcloud config set account <ACCOUNT>`.

Note that this access-token use is undocumented and could change without notice.